# webpack dev server error after npx create-react-app

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I run npx create-react-app and when I start it I get the error:
Module not found:

Error: Can't resolve 'D:#MyCode\React\playground\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10' in 'D:#MyCode\React\playground'

How can I fix this? All my previous projects that build with create-react-app also have this error.
I tried to delete and re-install node_modules. I deleted webpack-dev-server globally and reinstall it. Still I have this error everywhere. Only projects with custom webpack config still work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is actually with your system path to the react app. Make sure that none of the folder in the path to your react app contains #.

I was also facing the same issue and I removed # from the folder name and it starts working. For example : I have changed 'folderName#' to 'folderName'.

Comment: Thank you! You just saved my pc from defenestration.

Answer (score 3):

i also had this error. I simply terminated the project by pressing Ctrl+C then Y to confirm, and reloaded with npm start.

also if you type

```
npm audit fix --force
```

and then as it is updating make sure it updates react-scripts to 5.0^ then it should work. make sure you aren't running your project when updating this.